# Difference between VVVV.EmguCV and EmguCV.221.x64

Tags: emgucv

Can someone please throw some light on the difference between [VVVV.EmguCV](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VVVV.EmguCV/) and [EmguCV.221.x64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EmguCV.221.x64/). I am new to image processing itself.

Do they serve different purposes. As I understand they both are EmguCv wrappers to OpenCv. Is there any thing else to note?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VVVV.EmguCV` and `EmguCV.221.x64` are just two different packages by separate publishers.

`VVVV.EmguCV` installs the newer 2.4.X verison of EmguCV where as `EmguCV.221.x64` uses the 2.2.X series of Emgu.

Apart from the usual changes EmguCV 2.4.X added support for Android and iOS devices.You can check the difference between the versions [here.](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History_2.x)